# What to include in attribution/acknowledgements on iOS app using Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase

I have an application that uses Firebase Core, Firebase Database, Firebase Storage, and Firebase Messaging.

I've been looking around and I can't find what to put under an "Attributions" section in my app to credit Firebase.

What should I include in an "Attributions" section when I'm using Firebase in my app?

Thanks.

Comment: This question has been asked [in other places before](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/TG0KcFc3QLQ) and the answer is fuzzy (i.e. "depends on the Google API requirements").  Some Google API's (e.g. places and maps) do require "Powered by Google", but I don't see anything for "Powered by Google" attributions in relation to Firebase.  My opinion is that you're in the clear if you don't credit Firebase/Google in your Attributions.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Ok, thank you!